# Vite.js (Vue): Unwanted Page Reload Happens Only On Samsung Internet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a weird problem with `Vite.js` and it only happens on `Samsung Internet` when I'm on development server...

Problem: page reloads automatically 3 seconds in a loop and I don't set nor write any intervals... the page reload happens at browser level.

These are unwanted reloads and I want to get rid of them.

Any Idea why it happens?

Comment: @tony19
first I installed the app using: npm init vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue-ts and then run npm run dev -- --host.
After that navigate to the network IP address via a Samsung Mobile Browser.
I tested in latest 3 version of Samsung Internet Browser and it was there...

Comment: @Ehrlich_Bachman I just created the vite application and changed nothing..I created an [issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6796) in vite.js github too...

Comment: @mahatmanich I found the problem and it was not for Samsung Internet...I ran a debugger on Samsung Internet and the problem as exactly like this: `client.ts:28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://<local-ip>:3000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [Samsung Internet browser disallows insecure websockets](https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/is-there-any-method-to-disable-blocking-insecure-websocket-connection-in-version-16/17747).

A workaround is to enable HTTPS in Vite with [`server.https`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-https), so that it creates a secure Websocket:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  server: {
    https: true,
  }
})
```

*Verified with Vite 2.7.13 and Samsung Internet 16.0.6.23*

Answer (score 1):

**Edited asnwer:**

Ok so, I looked closer to this problem and I found some possible solutions.

Samsung Internet (same as Chrome) doesn't allow unsecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local web/websocket server). However the same should work fine with Firefox.

Another reason for this error could be "overloading" the same port. Maybe other app, which you are running, uses port 3000. The solution would be to stop that process or again change the port.

Testing solution: Does the code works if you do this?

```js
// Original line
new WebSocket(`${socketProtocol}://${socketHost}`, 'vite-hmr')


// Replace with exact url with port that you are running the app
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000")
```

Comment: I had different problem for developing for safari. So I changed browser for developing. Recommend swapping it.

Comment: I ran a debugger on Samsung Internet and the problem as exactly like this: `client.ts:28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://<local-ip>:3000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: This is the piece of [code](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/3949d21fa7a2962cc273ca78d1127ef984b88e4f/packages/vite/src/client/client.ts#L28) that causing the bug from `vite.js`..I think if I disable `hmr` from vite.js the problem would solve

Comment: The websocket is not in my codes. it's from `vite.js core`...

Comment: Vite.js uses `hmr` for hot reloading and to handle the updates it opens a websocket connection to the browser to listening for changes in codes in order to refresh the browser...The problem is from `Vite.js` core... take a look at this code: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/3949d21fa7a2962cc273ca78d1127ef984b88e4f/packages/vite/src/client/client.ts#L28

Comment: Changed my answer, is any method working?

Comment: @Atzuki No. I just enabled https server in vite.js configurations and it started working..It seems Samsung Internet browser disallows insecure websockets.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my 3rd paragraph, but ok. Atleast you figured it out.